# Why pass the address of char variable to standard read() function?

Tags: c

I'm learning C at the moment and wrapping my head around pointers. I understand `&` can be used to retrieve the address of a var in memory. I'm curious to know **why** this particular call to read() is passing the address of the char var.

Of course, the intention here is to read the input from shell 1 by 1, but why is it necessary to provide the address of `c`? Or is it merely a preference? I guess I'm not clear on when using a pointer is necessary.

```
int main() {
  char c;
  while (read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) == 1 && c != 'q');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you want a function to *modify* the variable you have outside of it (`c`), you pass its address, so it can write to it. C has pass-by-value only parameter passing.

Comment: Because [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) is documented to be used this way

Comment: You need to understand the difference btw parameters passed by value and by address (also called by reference). cf. this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/14393739) for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is it necessary to provide the address of c

`read()` needs an address to know where to store data.  `c` is a `char`.  To only pass `c` would pass the value of the `char` and not its address.  Hence code passed the address of `c`.

Alternatively,  form an array.  Code `read(array_name, ...)` will automatically convert the array to the address of its first element.

```
char c;
read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);

// or
char d[1];
read(STDIN_FILENO, d, 1);

// or 
#define N 42 /* or whatever */
char e[N];
read(STDIN_FILENO, e, sizeof e);
```

Comment: makes sense, cheers! I guess this could be used different if the read function returned a value that you could place in a variable, rather than modifying in place

Comment: @garethiv R  With `read(...,1)`, sure returning a `char` is easy, but with `read(..., N)`, not readily possible in C to return an _array_.

Comment: @garethiv From the caller's perspective, `read(STDIN_FILENO, e, sizeof e);` acts like pass-by-reference for `e`.  Yet from the `read()` point-of-view, it is still pass-by-value as it receives the address of `e` and `read()` needs to know the size of `e` via other means (`sizeof e`)